# Detect hidden telemetry in maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, security, intellij-idea

Recently I found a hidden call home / telemetry function in one of my project's maven dependencies. What is the best way to detect these kind of things?

Is there an easy way to get all the packages/classes listed that a particular maven dependency (and it's sub dependencies) depend on?
Many libraries that we are using should not require network communication or access to the file system. So a dependency on java.net.*, java.io.* etc. are clear indicators for a closer review.

I'm mainly using IntelliJ / Gradle.

Comment: That's exactly why I use Maven only when forced to. And then I start cleaning useless jars, which often represent 60-70% of the total.

Comment: @Matthieu What's the alternative?

Comment: Define "easy"... [jdeps](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jdeps.html#GUID-A543FEBE-908A-49BF-996C-39499367ADB4) can list dependencies of jars, and is contained in JDK packages. And its output can be filtered to look only for certain packages.

Comment: @Michael for relatively small projects get the *relevant* jars from mavencentral manually. For bigger projects you don't have much choice but to use maven then strip down manually. The problem is not specific to Maven but to all dependencies management software (pip, npm, apt, ...). You have to trade their ease of use to the pain the OP shows. I stay away from those as much as I can, but I understand most devs are not willing to...

Comment: @Matthieu "*The problem is not specific to Maven*", I'd argue it's not even a problem of Maven. Maven is doing exactly what you tell it to do. The problem is irresponsible library authors depending on libraries for basic functionality. The JavaScript ecosystem is the possibly worst for that, as exemplified by the whole [leftpad fiasco](https://qz.com/646467/how-one-programmer-broke-the-internet-by-deleting-a-tiny-piece-of-code). Libraries are starting to advertise themselves as having zero dependencies, and that's something I look for when possible.

Comment: @Hulk thanks for the hint regarding jdeps. I'll give it a try. I was hoping for an "easy" web tool that shows that information for any maven dependencies ;)

Comment: @Michael I'd give you a bounty for that comment ;) 0-dependencies is the #nofilter for libraires ;)

Comment: `Recently I found a hidden call home / telemetry function in one of my ` this means the dependency is wrong/maybe malicious... nothing to do with Maven you would have faced the same with Gradle or any other build tool. So you have to reconsider the usage of such dependencies. That means also that you don't use security scan tools etc. nor reporting about such things. That's general subject for all used dependencies. It sums up to: Do you trust the dependency? Are you using a a repository manager to have more control about the consumed deps?

Comment: There is also a question: Do those deps allow unrestricted usage? Does the documentation write something about this? If not I would suggest to start a CVE report about such kind of deps...

Comment: @Matthieu I would like see developing an spring boot/quarkus/micrometer/whatever app (execpt for toy projects) without using a build tool at all.. or go back to Ant(but that would raise up other issues)...

Comment: A suggesting is to remove all deps from your project and add step-by-step only those you really need... often people do not cleanup there deps after code changes etc. things like `mvn dependency:analyze` is a good start(https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html) that is not perfect but helps a lot...

Comment: @khmarbaise indeed ant is what I use ;) But as you said, it comes with other type of troubles. I chose mine ;)

Comment: I've worked with Ant a lot ... but left it behind more than 15 years ago... because of all other things.. Having a good look on deps and using the tools helps. Using Ant today in corporate/project development would be blocker in several ways.

Comment: Getting rid of maven/gradle is not what I'm looking for. The problem is not the dependency manager but that some dependencies contain "surprises", and my question was how to best detect these. You would have the same problem when adding every JAR manually.